# How can I fix "SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure" in my firebase function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, ssl, https, applepay

I'm trying to use a Firebase function to invalidate the merchantToken provided by apple using this api endpoint: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/merchanttokennotificationservices/invalidate_a_merchant_token?changes=latest_minor&language=objc_2

But I keep getting this error "SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure"
Here is my function

```
``
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as request from "request-promise";

interface ErrorResponse {
  errorMessage: string;
  httpResponseCode: number;
  statusCode: number;
}

export const unlinkMerchantToken = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  // Set the options for the POST request
  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    uri: "https://apple-pay-gateway.apple.com/v1/merchantId/{merchantId}/merchantToken/unlink",
    body: {
      data: data,
    },
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "x-request-id": String(Math.random()),
    },
    json: true,
  };

  // Make the POST request
  try {
    const response = await request(options);
    if (response.statusCode >= 201 && response.statusCode < 300) {
      // The request was successful
      return response.body;
    } else if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return response.body;
    } else {
      // The request was not successful
      const errorResponse: ErrorResponse = response.body;
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError("unknown", errorResponse.errorMessage, errorResponse);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    functions.logger.error(error);
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError("unknown", JSON.stringify(error));
  }
});

``
```

I tried using different https request libraries but I get the same error.

Comment: The server `apple-pay-gateway.apple.com` requires an TLS 1.2 connection. What device (OS version) do you use for testing? What happens if you open the URL in a web browser?

Comment: @Robert I tried making this request from my iPhone(iOS 16) and from Firebase server(so probably linux). And when I try it with Firefox it says:

An error occurred during a connection to apple-pay-gateway.apple.com. SSL peer was unable to negotiate an acceptable set of security parameters.

Error code: SSL_ERROR_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ALERT

    The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.

Comment: Then you have a problem with your internet connection. Most likely there is a man-in-the-middle server active. Some companies use such servers for traffic inspection. If your internet connection is at home using an ISP then you might be attacked.

Comment: @Robert I'm not sure I understand. I deployed this function to Google servers and I got the same error. How would my internet connection affect a function deployed on a Google server that's sending a request to Apple server?

Comment: What is "Google servers" in this context? What execution environment is running on that servers?

Comment: @Robert  Firebase functions running on node.js

Comment: What version of node.js? Does Node.js use the root CA list of the OS? If yes which OS is used?